# Filter Collection in ListBox using value of TextBlock in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, filter

I've created my own calendar. Each day in my calendar is an itemsControl which holds a textblock and a listbox, which should hold the items per date.

How do I filter a collection using the string value from the binded textblock in an ItemsControl?
The textblock is binded with the date property of the Day Class.

ViewModel

```
 public ObservableCollection<Day> Days { get; set; }

 public ObservableCollection<Scene> SceneList;

 private ListCollectionView _sceneCollection;
 public ListCollectionView SceneCollection
 {
     get
     {
         if (_sceneCollection == null) //important for loading the app
         {
             _sceneCollection = new ListCollectionView(this.SceneList);
             _sceneCollection.IsLiveFiltering = true;
             _sceneCollection.Filter = o =>
             {
                 var Scene = o as Scene;
                 return Scene != null && Scene.Date == ////string of binded TextBlock//;
             };
         }
         return _sceneCollection;
     }
     set
     {
         _sceneCollection = value; RaisePropertyChanged();
     }
 }
```

Model

```
public class Day : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private DateTime date;
     public DateTime Date
     {
        get { return date; }
        set
        {
            date = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Date"));
        }
     }
 }
```

Xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Days}">         
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="6" Columns="7">                     
                </UniformGrid>                  
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date , Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}, ConverterParameter=DAY}"/>                       
                    <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding SceneCollection}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
     dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" Height="100">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock>
                                     <Run Text="{Binding Path=SceneNumber}"/>
                                     <Run Text="{Binding Path=SlugLine}"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                   </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your ListBox's `ItemsSource` Binding will not work, since its DataContext is the Day object, and the `SceneCollection` property is not there, but in your ViewModel.

Also, you shouldn't filter your collection in your ViewModel, since all items will be bound to it and they'll need different filters.

In your case, if you wanna use filters and collection views while keeping the underlying collection intact, I'd simply add an 'ICollectionView' property to your 'Day' class, and assign each Day a filtered view of your SceneCollection.

Model:

```
public class Day : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set
        {
            date = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Date"));
        }
    }

    private ICollectionView scenes;
    public ICollectionView Scenes
    {
        get { return scenes; }
        set
        {
            scenes = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Scenes"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

ViewModel (example), in your Days collection initialization:

```
private IEnumerable<Day> CreateDaysData()
{
    var maxDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

    for (int d = 1; d <= maxDays; d++)
    {
        var day = new Day
        {
            Date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, d)
        };

        var viewSource = new CollectionViewSource
        {
            Source = ScenesCollection
        };

        viewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler((o, e) =>
        {
            e.Accepted = (e.Item as Scene).Date == day.Date;
        });

        day.Scenes = viewSource.View;

        yield return day;
    }
}
```

Finally, your XAML would end up like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Days}">         
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="6" Columns="7">                     
            </UniformGrid>                  
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date , Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}, ConverterParameter=DAY}"/>               
                <!-- The ListBox's ItemsSource is bound to the ICollectionView of your Day class -->        
                <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Scenes}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
 dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" Height="100">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock>
                                 <Run Text="{Binding Path=SceneNumber}"/>
                                 <Run Text="{Binding Path=SlugLine}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```